# How to change consitency level in YCSB?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-0.7, ycsb, fluentcassandra, cassandra-jdbc

I need to change the write and read consistency level of Cassandra ONE to QUORUM in YCSB. Whether, I need to change inside a Java client program or to pass as command line parameter. Please give me some suggestion

Answer (score 2):

`cassandra.writeconsistencylevel=QUORUM` property should work according to [this](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/pull/89).

Comment: Bhathiya i came across the link which you provide. They discuss but finally they did provide the correct way for a solution. PLease can you suggest where to pass the parameter.

Comment: try giving it as a property.
`-p cassandra.writeconsistencylevel=QUORUM`